# Bootstrap 3 - Dynamic affix and transparent collapse bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was looking for very long time for pretty solution for dynamic affix with Bootstrap 3 and finally my simply solution is below. Everything works great, except one feature. When i resize website to mobile and expand menu, whole list of menu items is transparent. When i starting scroll down, after the moment when navbar is affixed transparent problem does not exist. I read some posts that it can be caused by relative position for navbar but dont know how resolve this problem and dont loss my functionality.

```
<div id="nav-wrapper">
    <div id="nav" class="navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class=" collapse navbar-collapse navbar-center" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">ZESPÓL</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ZAPLECZE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GALERIA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MATERIALY</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">KONTAKT</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- navbar -->
</div>
```

js:

```
function myaffix() {
    var affixoffset = $('.navbar-inverse').offset().top
    $('#nav-wrapper').height($(".navbar-inverse").height());
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() <= affixoffset) {
            $('.navbar-inverse').removeClass('affix');
        } else {
            $('.navbar-inverse').addClass('affix');
        }
    });
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    myaffix();
    $(window).on("resize", function() {
        myaffix();
    });
});
```

and part of my css:

```
#nav.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%
}
#nav > .navbar-inner {
    border-left: 0;
}

.navbar-toggle
{
    float:none;

}
.navbar-header
{
    text-align:center;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Recreated your code here, https://output.jsbin.com/yeyite, but can't replicate the issue you are seeing. My guess is that there is something missing from the above code that is causing this problem.

Comment: @AndresIlich Hi Andres, finnaly i added position='relative' to my navbar-collapse div and everything works.